# Parse.com Cloud Code with moment.js plugin

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, momentjs

I'm trying to use a moment.js plugin (specifically moment-range.js) with Parse in Cloud Code. I can't seem to import it properly for the features of moment-range to work.

My main.js looks like:

```js
var moment = require("cloud/moment.js");
require("cloud/moment-range.js");
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'overlaps' of undefined
```

When trying to use the method overlaps of a null moment.range object.

How can I properly import moment-range.js?

Answer (score 0):

```
require('moment-range').range;
```